# How to access framework search path?

Tags: ios, xcode

I am new to iPhone development and to XCode.  I'm getting ld: building for iOS Simulator, but linking against dylib built for MacOSX file '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/XCTest.framework/XCTest' for architecture i386 when I try and run my project on a simulator.  I've tried linking frameworks in my XCode project, but I can't see them added to the framework search path, only as in the screenshot below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZCFQ.png

Comment: check you Linked Frameworks under Build Settings for your Tests target in Xcode. You should be able to remove the bad framework link there.

Comment: Sorry I still don't know how to do that.  I've tried going through the menus, and can't find one that says Build Settings.

Comment: Click on your Main Project in the left column, Under Targets, select YourProjectTest. Make sure the All selector is selected on the top (there is Basic and All). Search for Framework Search Paths.

Comment: Ok got there, but still unsure of what to replace $(SDKROOT)/Developer/Library/Frameworks
$(DEVELOPER_LIBRARY_DIR)/Frameworks
$(DEVELOPER_FRAMEWORKS_DIR) with.

Comment: I.e. what to replace the placeholders with.  I currently have DEVELOPER_FRAMEWORKS_DIR as /Applications/XCode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Applications/XCode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks

Comment: If you go over to Build Phases, still under your test target, and go to Link Binary With Libraries, do you see dylib in there?

Comment: I can't find the Build Phases now.  If I go to My ProjectTests and click the folder, all I can see is an .m file.

Comment: I added an answer that I will edit as I get more information.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Build Phases -> Linked Binary With Libraries of your MyProjectTests. They can be found here:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I can't see the one for AFNetworking :s.

Comment: The Frameworks for Tests, need to be the same as your main target. Add any missing frameworks to their.

Comment: When I try and add the AFNetworking header files using + and then 'Add More', they don't pop up in that folder (Build Phases), they just pop up under My Project - Frameworks.

Comment: You have the correct target selected? Can you edit your answer with a screen shot and maybe a bit more of your error?

Comment: I'm not sure how to add an image.  I will update the question.

Comment: I have added a screenshot, and have updated the question.  Is that any use?